# How to delete a RavenDB database with Raven.Client.Lightweight

Tags: ravendb

I have implemented what I believe to the proper way to delete a database (raven running as a service), based on the 1.2 Raven Studio's way of doing it and porting the code to a windows console.

```
static class Program
{    
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var store = new DocumentStore { ConnectionStringName = "RavenDB" }.Initialize())
            {

                var metadata = new RavenJObject();

                var factory = store.JsonRequestFactory;

                const string url = "http://localhost:8080/admin/databases/raven-products?hard-delete=true";

                var credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

                var convention = new DocumentConvention();

                var requestParams = new CreateHttpJsonRequestParams(store.DatabaseCommands, url, "DELETE", metadata, credentials, convention);

                var request = factory.CreateHttpJsonRequest(requestParams);

                request.ExecuteRequest();

            }

        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(exception);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key..");
        Console.ReadKey();

    }

}
```

When this code is executed , the following exception is raised.

> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
>     at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
>     at Raven.Client.Connection.HttpJsonRequest.ReadJsonInternal(Func`1 getResponse) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Unstable-v1.2\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Connection\HttpJsonRequest.cs:line 297
>     at Raven.Client.Connection.HttpJsonRequest.ReadResponseJson() in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Unstable-v1.2\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Connection\HttpJsonRequest.cs:line 218
>     at Raven.Client.Connection.HttpJsonRequest.ExecuteRequest() in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Unstable-v1.2\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Connection\HttpJsonRequest.cs:line 161
>     at Com.BuyEfficient.Raven.Service.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\code\buyefficient_mvc\Com.BuyEfficient\Com.BuyEfficient.Raven
>   .Service\Program.cs:line 39

My question is this "How do I correctly set up the credentials so that the console app is authenticated"?

Thank you,
Stephen

**UPDATE1**
 Code updated to reflect accepted answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use `CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials`, or supply the credentials of an admin user on the machine.

Comment: When the database is under load I am not able to delete. Instead I get this System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out.